# Coordinate variable type error

Tags: plotting, function-construction, warning-messages, data-types

I'm trying to implement a simple algorithm for curve subdivision, using a function with an input of an array of points to generate another array of new points and then putting them all into a new array which will maintain the order of the points as they are on the curve.

The problem is that in the output array the original points (with odd indices) and the new generated points (with even indices), the new points cannot be plotted, summing the original points works and summing the new points also works, however when I try to sum an original point with a new point, it is not handled correctly aswell. I provided an image of the code and illustrating the described problems.

```
pentagonpoints = Table[{-Sin[i*2*Pi/5], Cos[i*Pi*2/5]}, {i, 0, 5}];
fourpointscheme[pts_] := Module[{pts1 = pts, n = Length[pts]},
  addedpoints = 
   Table[(-1/16)*
      pts1[[If[Quotient[i, n + 1] > 0, i - n, i]]] + (9/16)*
      pts1[[If[Quotient[i + 1, n + 1] > 0, i + 1 - n, i + 1]]] + (9/
        16)*pts1[[
       If[Quotient[i + 2, n + 1] > 0, i + 2 - n, i + 2]]] - (1/
        16) pts1[[
       If[Quotient[i + 3, n + 1] > 0, i + 3 - n, i + 3]]], {i, 1, 
     n}];
  addedpoints = Prepend[addedpoints, Last[addedpoints]];
  addedpoints = Delete[addedpoints, -1] \.08;
  newpoints = 
   Table[If[Mod[i, 2] == 1, N[pts1[[(i + 1)/2]]], 
     N[addedpoints[[i/2]]]], {i, 1, 2*n}]]
firstiter = fourpointscheme[pentagonpoints]
firstiter[[2]] - firstiter[[4]]
firstiter[[1]] - firstiter[[3]]
firstiter[[1]] - firstiter[[2]]
Show[Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> 0.015, Point[firstiter]}], 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: My code]

Comment: There is a weird space after $y$ coordinates of some points, but I cannot readily spot where it came from. Can you please copy&paste your code in the question so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, I pasted the code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the line:

[image]

There is a space-like character before the semicolon. In fact, if I copy the actual code here, you will see that it is not an actual space, but a [backspace character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0008):

```
addedpoints = Delete[addedpoints, -1] \.08;
```

Delete it, and the code should work as expected.

Comment: Wow.. I would have never figured that out on my own I think. How do you even spot that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Weyr124 This is obvious reading the code text in your question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMEuW.png I'm wondering how you typed this character in your notebook?

Comment: @Weyr124, you start by looking at the `InputForm` or/and `FullForm`. But as xzczd mentioned, it is easier to spot such things if you copy&paste the code in a simple notepad.